# Proportionally Splitting a Data Frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) with 32,832 rows. Utilizing the split.seed function, how can I split it into two separate data frames? One with 80% of the rows of df, and the other with 20% of the rows of df?

I created one of the desired data frames by entering...

```
set.seed(123)
newDF <- df[sample(round(.8*nrow(df))),]
```

But I can't figure out how to get the remaining 20% of df into a separate frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the negative index:

```
set.seed(123)
sample_rows <- sample(round(.8*nrow(df)))

new_df_80 <- df[sample_rows,]
new_df_20 <- df[-sample_rows,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
split_df <- function(df, ratio=.8, seed=123, floor=TRUE) {
  set.seed(seed)
  rand_idxs <- sample(1:nrow(df))
  max_idx <- ifelse(floor, floor(ratio * nrow(df)), ceiling(ratio * nrow(df)))
  first_indexes <- rand_idxs[1:max_idx]
  second_indexes <- rand_idxs[(max_idx+1):nrow(df)]
  res <- list(df[first_indexes, ], 
              df[second_indexes, ])
  # attach info about used indexes
  attrs(res, "indexes") <- list(first_indexes, 
                                second_indexes)
  res
}
```

Usage:

```
dfs <- split_df(df, ratio=.8, seed=123, floor=TRUE)
dfs[[1]] # data frame of the 80% randomly selected rows
dfs[[2]] # data frame of the rest 20% rows
# retrieve indexes used for splitting
attrs(dfs, "indexes")
```

To save memory space, I save only the indexes used for train/test split together with the original `df`. It is very memory-saving to save only the indexes for the split and the split ratio.